# show that for each show that for each $T>\pi/2$, $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{T}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}dx <0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Show that for each $T>\pi/2$,

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{T}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}dx <0,$$

given we don't know anything regarding Ci(x) etc....

Comment: What are your thoughts?  HINT:  $\frac1x$ is decreasing and $\cos(x)<0$ when $\frac\pi2<x<\frac{3\pi}2$.

Comment: well I tried to sum a triangle below each peak, but it seems to diverge.

Comment: even if I'll show that this converges, how can I show it is negative?

Comment: Think about breaking the regions of integration up interms of intervals over which the sign of the cosine stays constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$f(x) = \dfrac{\cos(x)}{x}
$
and
$c(a, b)
=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx
$.

$f(x) < 0$ for
$\pi(2n+1/2)< x < \pi(2n+3/2)
$
and
$f(x) > 0$ for
$\pi(2n+3/2)< x < \pi(2n+5/2)
$.

If $0 < t < \pi$,

$\begin{array}\\
d(n, t)
&=c(\pi(2n+1/2), \pi(2n+1/2)+t)
-c(\pi(2n+3/2), \pi(2n+3/2)+t)\\
&=\int_{\pi(2n+1/2)}^{\pi(2n+1/2)+t}f(x)dx+\int_{\pi(2n+3/2)}^{\pi(2n+3/2)+t}f(x)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{t}f(x+\pi(2n+1/2))dx+\int_{0}^{t}f(x+\pi(2n+3/2))dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{t}(f(x+\pi(2n+1/2))+f(x+\pi(2n+3/2)))dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{t}(\dfrac{\cos(x+\pi(2n+1/2))}{x+\pi(2n+1/2)}+\dfrac{\cos(x+\pi(2n+3/2))}{x+\pi(2n+3/2)})dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{t}(\dfrac{\cos(x+\pi(2n+1/2))}{x+\pi(2n+1/2)}-\dfrac{\cos(x+\pi(2n+1/2))}{x+\pi(2n+3/2)})dx
\qquad\text{since } \cos(z) = -\cos(z+\pi)\\
&=\int_{0}^{t}\cos(x+\pi(2n+1/2))(\dfrac1{x+\pi(2n+1/2)}-\dfrac1{x+\pi(2n+3/2)})dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{t}(\dfrac{\pi(\cos(x+\pi(2n+1/2)))}{(x+\pi(2n+1/2))(x+\pi(2n+3/2))})dx\\
&\lt 0
\qquad\text{since } \cos(x+\pi(2n+1/2)) < 0\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
c(\pi(2n+1/2), \pi(2n+3/2)+t)
&=\int_{\pi(2n+1/2)}^{\pi(2n+3/2)+t}f(x)dx\\
&=\int_{\pi(2n+1/2)}^{\pi(2n+1/2)+t}f(x)dx+\int_{\pi(2n+1/2)+t}^{\pi(2n+3/2)}f(x)dx+\int_{\pi(2n+3/2)}^{\pi(2n+3/2)+t}f(x)dx\\
&=d(n, t)+\int_{\pi(2n+1/2)+t}^{\pi(2n+3/2)}f(x)dx\\
&\lt 0
\qquad\text{since } d(n, t) < 0 \text{ and } f(x) < 0 \text{ for } 
\pi(2n+1/2)+t < x < \pi(2n+3/2)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
for $0 < t < \pi$,
$\int_{\pi(2n+1/2)}^{\pi(2n+1/2)+t}f(x)dx
\lt 0$
since $f(x) < 0$ in the range,
and
$\int_{\pi(2n+1/2)}^{\pi(2n+3/2)+t}f(x)dx
\lt 0$.

Comment: thanks I believe this what I looked for.

Comment: You are welcome. I like making hand-waving rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the integral is strictly increasing on some intervals, and strictly decreasing everywhere else. So it is sufficient to consider local maximum points $\pi/2+2i\pi, i\in \{0,1,2,...\}$ because if not, then we could either get a bigger sum by moving forward to a local max, or a bigger sum by moving backwards to a local max.

Consider T=$\pi/2$. This is the highest point the integral ever attains because in order to get the next positive contribution of $\int_{3pi/2}^{5\pi/2}\frac{cos(x)}{x}dx$, we have to incur the cost of $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{cos(x)}{x}dx$.

And because of the x in the denominator, $|\int_{3pi/2}^{5\pi/2}\frac{cos(x)}{x}dx| < |\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{cos(x)}{x}dx)|$.

In general, $|\int_{(i+2)pi/2}^{(i+4)\pi/2}\frac{cos(x)}{x}dx| < |\int_{i\pi/2}^{(i+2)\pi/2}\frac{cos(x)}{x}dx)|$ for i=1,3,5,...

So, we may never attain a bigger value than $\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{cos(x)}{x}dx=0$.

Comment: I understand what you say, but it seems non-formal, how do I show "because of the x in the denominator..."?

Comment: even if I accept this, how do we know that in any given point for example at the i-th  period at its peak, the integral isn't positive?

Comment: |cos(x+pi/2)/(x+pi/2)| < |cos(x)/x| for all x in that interval. therefore, the integral is less

Comment: the integral isn't positive because we can write the integral of the whole thing as the integral of each interval added together. And in order to get the next positive piece, we have to incur a negative greater than the positive could ever make up for

Comment: sure, you could make the argument more formal by saying it's strictly increasing on such and such interval, so it is sufficient to consider such and such local maximum points because if not, then we could either get a bigger sum by moving forward to a local max, or a bigger sum by moving backwards to a local max

Answer (score 0):

This can be seen from the graph of $ f(x) = \frac{\cos{x}}{x}$:
[image: cosx/x]
Considering $x \geq \frac{\pi}{2}$, every section where $f(x) <  0$ bounds a larger (magnitude) area than the following section where $f(x) >  0$;
for a point $ f(x_1) = \frac{\cos x_1}{ x_2}$, then the corresponding point in the next section at $x_2=x_1 + \pi$   has $f(x_2) = \frac{\cos{(x_1 + \pi)}}{x} = -\frac{\cos{x_1}}{x_2}$, so $ |f(x_2)| < |f(x_1)|$ as $x_2 > x_1$.

We can conclude that each negative area is greater in magnitude than the following positive area as at each corresponding pair of points, the function has a smaller magnitude in the positive area. It follows that any adjacent pair of negative and positive sections (with the positive section starting at greater $x$) will have a net area less than zero.

Hence, we can conclude the net area bounded from $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $x = T$ , given by the definite integral of $f(x)$, must be negative as the first section in this interval is negative so the net area of any pair of negative and positive areas partially contained in the interval will be negative, while all complete pairs of areas will have negative net area.

Comment: first, thanks, though this isn't the formal explanation, that I've looked for.